# HttpClient PostAsync model is null, however it works in Postman

Tags: c#, http

I'm making a call using HttpClient.

```
var serializedRequest= JsonConvert.SerializeObject(searchRequest);
var stringContent = new StringContent(serializedRequest, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync(url, stringContent);
```

The object is null in the API controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public List<string> GetSearchResults([System.Web.Http.FromBody]SearchRequest searchRequest)
```

However, if I make the same call from Postman (I copied the serialized object within Visual Studio while debugging), it works. Why would that be the case? I'm trying to figure out how to send the content length with the request, but apparently that's supposed to be happening already by using `StringContent`.

The caller is .NET Core 2.2 and the API is .NET Framework 4.7.2.

EDIT:

This was the original call:

```
var response = await _httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(url, searchRequest);
```

That does NOT work even when the API method isn't using `[FromBody]`. Looks like I need to use the above code (`StringContent`) along with the API method not using `[FromBody]`. What's weird is that a coworker isn't having this issue. It's just on my machine. Go figure.

Comment: Getting rid of `[FromBody]` might be fixing it. Checking...

Comment: `System.Web.Http.FromBody` looks like WebAPI but `HttpPost` and the `List<string>` as a result seems to indicate a MVC controller.

Comment: I'm wondering if it's a .NET Core issue calling .NET Framework. `[FromBody]` in .NET Core is in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc. In .NET Framework 4.7.2 it's in System.Web.Http. In any case, removing [FromBody] is working. Since it's a complex type, that's where it will be found anyway. The attribute is unnecessary in this case.

Comment: What's interesting is that it works from postman. I'd set up a fiddler proxy and compare both clients down to a single character sent.

Comment: Does CO- Worker use same default Browser that you use?  The content type header in http is based on default browser and may be different on two machines.   There may be other differences so use a browser like wireshark or fiddler and compare the headers in first request on working and non working machine.